# Kakfa broker v2.1.0 gets into stuck state after LeaderEpochCache truncation

Tags: apache-kafka

We are running a 3 broker kafka cluster (v2.11-2.1.0), r4.xlarge machines on aws.We have cpu usage upto 85%, memory usage nearing 99%(including i/o buffers). We have 3 node zk cluster. we have around ~80-90k messages/sec load

`broker java env:`

> java -Xmx7982m -Xms7770m -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xloggc:/home/kafka/kafka/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M```

Usually producers and consumers dont face any issues, but intermittently below log errors are written in "server.log"

```
2019-05-27 20:21:53,211] WARN [LeaderEpochCache pulse-flattening-errors-23] New epoch entry EpochEntry(epoch=2, startOffset=0) caused truncation of conflicting entries ListBuffer(EpochEntry(epoch=1, startOffset=0)). Cache now contains 1 entries. (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
[2019-05-27 20:23:45,175] WARN [LeaderEpochCache pulse-21-feb-error-message-16] New epoch entry EpochEntry(epoch=4, startOffset=1833) caused truncation of conflicting entries ListBuffer(EpochEntry(epoch=3, startOffset=1833)). Cache now contains 2 entries. (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
[2019-05-27 20:23:45,269] WARN [LeaderEpochCache pulse-21-feb-error-message-28] New epoch entry EpochEntry(epoch=4, startOffset=1525) caused truncation of conflicting entries ListBuffer(EpochEntry(epoch=3, startOffset=1525)). Cache now contains 2 entries. (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
[2019-05-27 20:23:45,339] WARN [LeaderEpochCache pulse-21-feb-error-message-4] New epoch entry EpochEntry(epoch=4, startOffset=1427) caused truncation of conflicting entries ListBuffer(EpochEntry(epoch=3, startOffset=1427)). Cache now contains 2 entries. (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
[2019-05-27 20:23:45,529] WARN [LeaderEpochCache pulse-21-feb-error-message-10] New epoch entry EpochEntry(epoch=4, startOffset=2430) caused truncation of conflicting entries ListBuffer(EpochEntry(epoch=3, startOffset=2430)). Cache now contains 2 entries. (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
[2019-05-27 20:23:45,577] WARN [LeaderEpochCache pulse-21-feb-error-message-22] New epoch entry EpochEntry(epoch=4, startOffset=1802) caused truncation of conflicting entries ListBuffer(EpochEntry(epoch=3, startOffset=1802)). Cache now contains 2 entries. (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache
```

Obvservations:

> - Above warnings occur on leader of a particular partition
> - broker while still listening on port 9092, stops responding to any producer requests.
> - producers timeout and not able to send messages to cluster
> - Other brokers fail replication hence they also get stuck
> - New leader is not elected
> - All producers fail

I have Checked config for the topics and partitions , nothing seems to be out of ordinary. Mostly maintaining defaults of the apache kafka distribution v2.11-2.1.0 
unclean leader election is also set to false for the cluster as well as topics.
This has been happening intermittently and repeatedly.

I have checked issues.apache.org for related issues, could not find any relevant matching issue.

This is making our cluster unstable and causes full downtime to producers. Dont have any clue in which direction to start looking

Comment: Found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807993/kafka-new-version-2-1-0-broker-hangs-for-no-reason